# How to verify if a certificate is hashed with SHA-1 in Java

Tags: java, sha

In Java to get the signature algorithm associated with an X509 certificate I can do:
`X509Certificate.getSigAlgName()`to return a human-friendly algorithm name, e.g `SHA1WithRSA`.

Is there a way to find out if the signature algorithm returned by the function above is using SHA-1 as it's hashing function? other than having a list of algorithms like so [`SHA1WithRSA`, `SHA1WithDSA`, `SHA1WithECSDA`...] and verifying if the algorithm name is in the list .

Comment: Since the list of possible algorithms is standardized, having a white list that you want to accept seems like a good plan.

Comment: Are you using JCE or some provider like BouncyCastle?

Comment: @Thilo: not for X.509; `AlgorithmIdentifier` is _by design_ open-ended. _PKIX_, which is _most_ X.509 _on the Internet_ (not all uses) doesn't set any limits, though people mostly _use_ only positively defined RFCs like 3279 4055 4491(!) 5480 5758. The closest is that TLS1.3 requires and earlier versions allow using sigalgs or sigalgscert, which are limited by a mutable-but-not-easily IANA registry, unless you do private-use which is theoretically possible but vanishingly rare. OTOH the list implemented by Java provider(s) is limited, and (runtime) enumerable.